# Fetching the data extension created by

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I am trying to fetch all the meta information about data extensions. I am successful in fetching the name, external key, folder path, row count. However, my client would like to see the created by and last modified by of the data extension. (the info which is there on UI). I have tried looking up the data extension object, but I don't see anything that relates to this. I have also looked at the Account User object with no luck. Has anyone managed to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the actual users and not the dates (dates are available via SOAP Object), the only way I know of to get this information is via an 'Internal' REST API endpoint which we do not have access to.

For example if you go into Contact Builder and watch the network tab, it will point to this REST Endpoint:

```
GET https://www-mc-{{stack}}.exacttargetapis.com/internal/v1/customobjects/{{deID}}
```

Which, as you may guess by the 'internal' part, it will not accept the authentication we receive via the current OAuth token from our REST applications. Which means we are not able to access this without an 'internal' auth token.

But this Endpoint returns pretty much all the information on any DE that you would ever want. It is a shame that endpoints like this as well as many others (LOOKING AT YOU CLOUD PAGES) are not released to public, but unfortunately that is current state.

Comment: Yes you are right, I mean created by and modified by (not the date- this i already fetched), and i tried the exactly same api, but as rightly mentioned , it is not accessible :( Hoping there is an open idea for this on idea exchange

Answer (score 0):

Last Modified is accessible by way of the API through the DataExtension object (using SOAP routes) (Info here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextension.htm) - it looks like you may be able to derive some other meta-creation data as well, relating to either that object or another

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am not looking for modified by date, but the actual user who created the DE and last modified it :)