# Get ModifiedBy user ID that most recently modified a DataExtention

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm making this SOAP API call to get info about data extensions in a targeted business unit.  The only real piece of information I need is: **who last modified the data extension.**  In looking at the DataExtension object in Salesforce Marketing Cloud, I don't see 'ModifiedBy' or anything similar field that would identify the user that did the last modification.  Any direction on where I would find that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This unfortunately is not possible by an external API we have access to or any other process available to us. You would only be able to get this information via an internal API or via the UI.  None of the REST nor SOAP API calls have this information as a possible property in the return.

You can see some details in this **[answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/331954/fetching-the-data-extension-created-by/332001#332001)** about 'Created by', which is identical to your request on 'Modified By'.

Below is a quick snippet of that answer:

> For example if you go into Contact Builder and watch the network tab, it will point to this REST Endpoint:
>
> ```
> GET https://www-mc-{{stack}}.exacttargetapis.com/internal/v1/customobjects/{{deID}}
> ```
>
> Which, as you may guess by the 'internal' part, it will not accept the authentication we receive via the current OAuth token from our REST applications. Which means we are not able to access this without an 'internal' auth token.

I would love for users to push these requests for API functionality to the **[ideas page](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaSearch)** or other avenues to let SFMC know how useful and in-demand these capabilities are. Without this information or push for capabilities, they will not realize where they need to put effort.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I appreciate your feedback and will absolutely create a post on the ideas page to help further the cause.  Thank you for taking the time to respond.